# Exported variables from zshrc not available in WebStorm Run Configuration

Tags: zsh, webstorm

I set up an `NPM_TOKEN` in my `.zshrc` file. When I run `yarn start` in a *terminal* my Gatsby app runs fine, but when I create an NPM run configuration in WebStorm for `start`, it can't find the token:

```
error An unexpected error occurred: "Failed to replace env in config: ${NPM_TOKEN}".
```

I actually get the same error when attempting to commit from Webstorm. Works fine in terminal (even the WS terminal)

I have Fig installed, and ohmyzsh, and here is my `.zshrc` file.

```bash
[[ -f "$HOME/.fig/shell/zshrc.pre.zsh" ]] && builtin source 
"$HOME/.fig/shell/zshrc.pre.zsh"

export ZSH="$HOME/.oh-my-zsh"

ZSH_THEME="robbyrussell"

plugins=(git)

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh

source ~/.zprofile    # loads some custom aliases using "source 
.aliases/some_alias_file.zsh" etc

export NPM_TOKEN="my token"

[[ -f "$HOME/.fig/shell/zshrc.post.zsh" ]] && builtin source "$HOME/.fig/shell/zshrc.post.zsh"

export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
```

Is there a way to fix this?

**UPDATE:** Adding my `NPM_TOKEN` to `.bashrc` fixed this. So I guess Webstorm is running bash, or reading that file, instead of zsh and reading its config files? We're slightly over my head at this point. But I would imagine there's a way to configure this?

Comment: what OS is it? Try starting the IDE [from terminal](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011901879-How-to-start-IDE-from-the-command-line#h_9eb22313-2b74-4d6c-996e-6fb08dacc95f) to get it inherit the terminal environment - does the issue persist?

Comment: That did work; although I also quit webstorm and then opened it as usual, and that also worked. Either way, I seem to be good :)